# Is it possible to install Ubuntu to ACER Iconia Tab?

Tags: 22.04, acer

I have an old tablet ACER Iconia Tab. The Windows 7 installed there.
Is it possible to install Ubuntu to this tablet?
Does anybody have any experience with this tablet?